# Tengo un problema en correr el programa con un error. "Cannot read the array length because "dama" is null"

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa de una tienda de ropa, en el que por medio de un archivo de texto introduzco el departamento (dama,caballero,niño), el tipo de prenda, el color, el id de la prenda. El programa tiene que contener un menu que depende de la opcion que introduzca el usuario, tiene que salir el departamento de dicha prenda. por ejemplo, si el usuario quiere ver todas las prendas de dama, tiene que salir todas las prendas de damas y asi sucesivamente con el precio y el id.

esto es lo que tengo por ahora.

la clase de departamento

```
package proyecto1estruc;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Departamentos {

    
    private String [] nino;
    private String [] caballeros;
    private String [] dama;
    private int[] leerdama;
    private String[] codigos;
    
    public Departamentos( ) {
        
        this.nino = nino;
        
        this.caballeros = caballeros;
        
        this.dama = dama;
        
        this.leerdama = new int [24];
        
        this.codigos = codigos;
        
        
        
        
}
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        
        Departamentos objDepartamentos = (Departamentos ) obj; 
         if (nino ==  objDepartamentos.nino
                 && dama == objDepartamentos.dama
                 && caballeros == objDepartamentos.caballeros)
             
             
              return true;
         else
            return false;
    }


public String toString() {
    
    return "La prenda permetenece al departamento de ninos: " + this.nino + "La prenda pertenece al departamento de damas: " + this.dama + "La prenda pertenece al departamento de caballeros: " + this.caballeros;
}
public String[] getNino() {
    return nino;
}
public void setNino(String[] nino) {
    this.nino = nino;
}
public String[] getCaballeros() {
    return caballeros;
}
public void setCaballeros(String[] caballeros) {
    this.caballeros = caballeros;
}
public String[] getDama() {
    return dama;
}
public void setDama(String[] dama) {
    this.dama = dama;
}


public String[] getCodigos() {
    return codigos;
}
public void setCodigos(String[] codigos) {
    this.codigos = codigos;
}
public void setleerdama (Scanner fileScan ) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    String [] dama = new String[25];
    
    
    int count = 0;
    
    
    while(fileScan.hasNextLine()){
        String linea = fileScan.nextLine();
        String [] info = linea.split(" ");
        
        for(int i=0; i < info.length; i++) {
            String [] lineaCompleta = linea.split(" ");
            
            dama[count] = lineaCompleta[0] + " " + lineaCompleta[1]; // informacion de la prenda 
            
        }
        
        count++;
    
        
}
}

}

*****el main***** 

package proyecto1estruc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oldNavy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
        int entero = 0; 
        
        
        Departamentos dama = new Departamentos();
        
        File file = new File("//Users//myrzabelarceescobar//Documents//eclipse-projects//proyecto1estruc//src//Prendas de ropa");
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner (file);
        
        dama.getDama();
        
         Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        
         System.out.println ("Escribe / para comenzar ");
            char option = scan.next().charAt(0);
        
        while (option == '/') {
        
             System.out.println ("Presiona 1 ");
             entero= scan.nextInt();
        
        
        if (entero == 1)
             
         {
             
             
             leerdamas(dama.getDama());
             
            System.out.println ("Escribe / para comenzar ");
             option = scan.next().charAt(0);
            
             
                
         }
        
        else if (entero != 1) {
             System.out.println ("Lo siento, solo se puede 1");
         }
         }
    }
        
        
         static void leerdamas(String [] dama) {
            for(int i = 0; i < dama.length; i++) {
                if(dama[i] == null)
                    System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + dama[i]);
```

Si me pueden ayudar de verdad que se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema viene al momento de llamar esta función

```
 leerdamas(dama.getDama());
```

Ya que esta función pide como parámetro `String [] dama`

Y luego intenta leer su propiedad `length` de ese parámetro

```
 static void leerdamas(String [] dama) {
     for(int i = 0; i < dama.length; i++) {
         ...
```

Entonces el `String [] dama` que le pasas es `dama.getDama()`

Si nos vamos a esa función vemos que retorna `dama` de la clase.

```
public String[] getDama() {
    return dama;
}
```

Todo eso parece estar bien, salvo una cosa y es tu problema, dama vale `null`.

Cuando haces esto

```
private String [] dama;
```

Le estás diciendo a `java` que tipo es esa variable, en este caso un **arreglo de strings** pero no le estás dando valor. Es decir, por el momento tu variable vale `null` hasta que la iniciales.

Como `dama = null` entonces cuando haces esto `for(int i = 0; i < dama.length; i++)` estás diciendo que `i < null.length` y null no tiene esa propiedad, no tiene ninguna.

Solución.

Inicializa tu variable.

```
private String [] dama = new String[25];
```

Si quieres que cambie respecto a objetos, es decir que un objeto Departamentos tenga 25, otro 20, etc. puedes iniciarla en el constructor.

```
public Departamentos(String[] dama) {
            
    this.nino = nino;
    this.caballeros = caballeros;
    this.dama = dama;
    this.leerdama = new int [24];
    this.codigos = codigos;
}
```

Después puedes crear objetos.

Departamentos olNavy = new Departamentos(new String[25])
Departamentos tommyHighFilger = new Departamentos(new String[50])

Entonces

```
oldNavy.getDama().length // valdrá 25
tommyHighFilger.getDama().length // valor 50
```

NOTA: Casi todos los **atributos** de tu clase tienen ese problema. Si se te llega a volver a presentar algo con `null` es que te falta inicializarlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero intente lo que me sugeriste que es inicializar la variable dama (private String [] dama = new String[25];) pero sigue dando el mismo error y me dice que es por esta linea ( for(int i = 0; i < dama.length; i++) { ) y por esta ( leerdamas(dama.getDama()); ).

Comment: en que lunea inicializaste eso?

Comment: al principio del todo, pero gracias ya resolvi